# Use list items as keys for nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to use the items in a list as dictionary keys to find a value in nested dictionaries.

For example, given the following list:

```
keys = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

I want to do:

```
result = dictionary[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]]
```

Which would be the equivalent of:

```
result = dictionary['first']['second']['third']
```

But I don't know how many items will be in the `keys` list beforehand (except that it will always have at least 1).

Comment: have you tried `addict.Dict` - that's probably the easiest way. Otherwise of course you can iterate with `.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Iteratively go into the subdictionaries.

```
result = dictionary
for key in keys:
  result = result[key]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for-loop will work:

```
result = dictionary[keys[0]]  # Access the first level (which is always there)
for k in keys[1:]:            # Step down through any remaining levels
    result = result[k]
```

Demo:

```
>>> dictionary = {'first': {'second': {'third': 123}}}
>>> keys = ['first', 'second', 'third']
>>> result = dictionary[keys[0]]
>>> for k in keys[1:]:
...     result = result[k]
...
>>> result
123
>>>
```

Comment: You should try, except or use get and break on None.

Comment: Why?  `keys` is supposed to be a list of valid keys.  If it contains one that does not exist, I would expect a `KeyError` to be raised.  Suppressing this error would only lead to problems down the line.